# Why does iri use manual neighbor discovery?

Tags: neighbors, nodesharing

The process of pairing with neighbours on slack #nodesharing is tedious. Why doesn't iri use automatic discovery of neighbors like other p2p networks?

Answer (score 3):

Visit ["Discussion: Removing Peer Discovery"](https://forum.iota.org/t/discussion-removing-peer-discovery/939) to read about it.

To quote briefly from the discussion:

> [...] we've collected enough data to be able to determine that Peer Discovery is causing more problems than it does good.

[...]

> ### The Problems
>
> **Snapshotting**: Peer Discovery basically makes it possible for previousu
> transactions to be rebroadcast and picked up by the majority of the
> network. Thus coming back to pre-snapshot state.
>
> **Difficulty Adjustment**: Difficulty is supposed to self-adjust according to the network topology (tps, etc.), with PD this difficulty adjustment does
> not work as intended.
>
> **Bandwidth**: The bandwidth consumption increases
> exponentially, so if we want to have a system fit for running in IoT
> where every tiny bit of resource is scarce, we have such a waste.
>
> **Syncing**: Currently syncing is fairly slow - without PD it should speed
> up.